# How to send file as a parameter of POST request in REST Client in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, rest-client

I want to send `<MYURL>/myaddres?path=<MYPATH>&content=<MYCONTENT>` to a service with editor based REST client in IntelliJ, but take the content of `<MYCONTENT>` from a file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should type the `<` symbol followed by the path to the file:POST

```
POST http://example.com:8080/api/html/post
Content-Type: application/json

< ./input.json
```

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#provide-request-body

Comment: Yes, but this will pass file as entire request body, not for a single parameter?